# 2 Computers 1 USB Device (circuit help)

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, usb-device

I have a project with a custom USB device that pumps out a stream of data every 1.125 seconds to a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT, and occasionally receives an 8-byte command. The USB device and the Raspberry Pi are in a custom enclosure and I've got a nice touchscreen going for basic interactivity.

I was kicking around the idea of having the option of plugging a real PC into the device and having that take over the operation of the USB device. **Let's consider the device-to-Pi connection to be permanent, and that I can wire an external USB port to my enclosure that connects to the device.** I understand that USB is a point-to-point protocol and I can't just use a y-cable. I am able to modify the USB device at the PCB level.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I'd like the device to detect when a PC has plugged in and override the device-to-Pi connection and permit two-way communication with the PC while it's connected.

BOUNS POINTS: Is there a way to still *receive* the data stream at the Raspberry Pi? This would solve some datalogging issues.

I did find this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5usbc400.pdf. It sounds like it might work (I can use Vbus of the PC to toggle the logic somehow, maybe), just glancing at the datasheet. However, this doesn't solve the problem of the bonus question.

If it helps, the USB device uses an NXP MK66FX1M0VLQ18 microcontroller.

Comment: 2 Computers 1 USB device, is this something... crazy?

Comment: @HarrySvensson no, I wish. It's an environmental monitoring device, but I'm trying to not overload the RPi by asking it to do a bunch of real-time graphs and such. I can also forsee a few use cases where using the touchscreen exclusively may be problematic (like crazy monitoring locations, etc).

Comment: This just isn't how USB is intended to work.

Comment: Why not have the PC get the data from the Pi over ethernet?

Comment: @ThePhoton I hadn't considered that. That's a pretty great idea, actually.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I get that two *simultaneous* hosts isn't the right way to go, but by using a switch which has one selected at all times seems reasonable. Maybe my bonus question isn't possible, but switching hosts should be. There are commercial products that can do it, I'd just rather implement it at the board level.

Comment: Those commercial products do the same as the switch you posted.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: I see what you did there.

Comment: USB is intentionally a point-to-point connection because it has no software or hardware to share data. Splicing in another USB cable would result in severe data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

5 options:

1, use the usb switch you mentioned. Or one that can also switch power. That's exactly what they were designed to do.

2, use the second usb interface on the NXP device, and disconnect from the first usb interface/RPi when it detects a connection.

3, use both usb interfaces that your microcontroller has at the same time, one per host. Code the product to respond to only one control interface but spit data at both.

4, use the RPi as a middle man, not having the "real" (what is real ) pc connect to the usb device, but to the rpi via network, or the RPi usb peripheral connection.

5, use an alternative to usb, like bluetooth, ethernet, or wireless. Frankly, that microcontroller can act like a real pc as well.

Comment: Your suggestion #3 is completely unrealistic. Two hosts will emit periodic SOFs, and due to natural frequency differences between two hosts the SOF from one host will collide with EOF1-EOF2 prohibited interval of the second host, and second host will disconnect due to "babbling" condition after few minutes. And many other packet collisions will occur, because of no synchronization between host schedulers.

Comment: #4 is the best solution, Rpi-Zero-W will do. Verified.

Comment: @ale the microcontroller has two usb interfaces, both can be used at the same time. The USB packets would get replied to, the higher level control messages can be ignored. Ops data collector program may not even need to be modified.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your #3. Two different devices on same SoC will work, agree.